# Keeping data in old Database (SQL 2008) identical to new Database (SQL 2016)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, sql-server-2016

I am moving database to new server.

New server has SQL Server 2016 running, current server has SQL Server 2008.

I need to have backup/fallback plan in place for few weeks (in case something goes wrong - I can switch my application back to 2008 Server and continue working).

I am wondering is it possible to enable replication (or alternatives?) and have all transactions/merges be in sync on 2008 Instance so both databases are up to date in case I need to switch to old one?

Due to business requirements, we *must* be able to fall back to SQL Server 2008.  This is non-negotiable.

Answer (score 7):

Converted from comments:

> According to [Replication Backward Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-ver15), Transactional Replication will not work between a 2016 Publisher and a 2008 Subscriber, but [Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) would be supported. Check out Merge Replication to see if that will suit your needs. – [Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin)
>
> Or Upgrade to 2014 and it will be backward compatible to 2008 for transactional replication. Once You have a steady ship, you can move ahead to later versions if needed. – [Ramakant Dadhichi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/128145/ramakant-dadhichi)

Answer (score 7):

> I am wondering is it possible to enable replication (or alternatives?)
>   and have all transactions/merges be in sync on 2008 Instance so both
>   databases are up to date in case I need to switch to old one?

It's a bit complex, but you could introduce a SQL Server 2014 server to serve as Transactional Replication Subscriber and [Republisher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/republish-data?view=sql-server-ver15).

But the only other option is to develop a set of scripts that move all the changes from the SQL 2016 database and apply them to the SQL 2008 database.  Or use the [database import/export wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15). If the probability of executing the fallback is low enough, and you have sufficient time to do this, this might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can have some downtime for a downgrade you can also export whole database as a dacpac and then import it into a lower version.
It is often a preferred method for moving databases between onprem and Azure.

Follow this instructions for an export:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-ver15